# Celery task always PENDING for task in different file

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to refactor my tasks into its own file. However, this leads to job status not being  updated - it is always in `PENDING` state. The task runs fine though.

This is my `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from celery.task.control import inspect

from jobs import task_one
from factory import create_app, create_celery

app = create_app()
celery = create_celery(app)


@app.route('/run', methods=['GET'])
def run_task():
    # run job in celery
    task = task_one.run()
    return jsonify(name=app.name, status='Task is running', taskid=task.id), 202


@app.route('/status/<taskid>', methods=['GET'])
def task_status(taskid):
    task = celery.AsyncResult(taskid)
    return jsonify(status=task.state)


def main():
    app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my `factory.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'amqp://127.0.0.1'
    app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'rpc'
    app.config['CELERY_TRACK_STARTED'] = True

    return app


def create_celery(app=None):
    app = app or create_app()
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

This is my `jobs/task_one.py`

```
from time import sleep    
from celery import chain    
from factory import create_celery

celery = create_celery()


@celery.task(name='jobs.long_running_task', bind=True)
def long_running_task(self, x, y):
    sleep(15)
    print 'running:', x, y
    return x + y


@celery.task(name='jobs.long_mapping_task', bind=True)
def long_mapping_task(self, x, y):
    sleep(15)
    print 'mapping:', x, y
    return x + y


def run():
    task = chain(long_running_task.s(1,2), long_mapping_task.s(4))()
    return task
```

So, I run `rabbitmq`, celery by issuing `celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=debug --concurrency=1`, and running the Flask application by `python app.py`.

The task will run fine, but the job status is always pending.

Now, if I make everything into one file, it works just fine. The following code should work:

```
from time import sleep

from flask import Flask, jsonify
from celery import Celery, chain
from celery.task.control import inspect


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'amqp://127.0.0.1'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'rpc'
app.config['CELERY_TRACK_STARTED'] = True

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)


@celery.task(bind=True)
def long_running_task(self, x, y):
    sleep(15)
    print 'running:', x, y
    return x + y


@celery.task(bind=True)
def long_mapping_task(self, x, y):
    sleep(15)
    print 'mapping:', x, y
    return x + y


@app.route('/run', methods=['GET'])
def run_task():
    # run job in celery
    task = chain(long_running_task.s(1,2), long_mapping_task.s(4))()
    return jsonify(name=app.name, status='Job is running', taskid=task.id), 202

@app.route('/status/<taskid>', methods=['GET'])
def task_status(taskid):
    task = celery.AsyncResult(taskid)

    return jsonify(status=task.state)


def main():
    app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I don't understand why this is happening and how to solve this. I've seen other solutions posted here in SO but none of those worked in my case. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you do have 2 celery instances:

**app.py** `celery = create_celery(app)`

and

**jobs/task_one.py** `celery = create_celery()`

You should share the celery instance created in **app.py** in **jobs/task_one.py** by importing it:

```
from app import celery
```

Note that you may need to move the statement `from jobs import task_one` to avoid circular dependency between `app` and `task_one` modules

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my day. I didn't know that I can't have 2 celery instances pointing at the same queue.